# ReferenceError: variable not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new b to JS, any help would be appreciated

have following code

```
<head>
  <script language="Javascript">
      function my(eve)
      {
        // Internet Explorer
        if (eve.srcElement)
        {
          alert(eve.srcElement.nodeName);
        }
        // Netscape and Firefox
          else if (eve.target)
        {
          alert(eve.target.nodeName);
        }
      };
</script>
</head>
<body onmousemove="my(eve);">
  //Some HTML code
</body>
```

Getting Error in FF Console while moving mouse over the browser window-

```
"ReferenceError: eve is not defined

my(eve);"
```

Comment: Did you mean `event`?

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to do this:

```
<body onmousemove="my(event);">
```

That is, you wanted to pass the `event` object to your `my()` function. Then within that function you can refer to it by the `eve` variable. (Note that it is very common to define an event variable with the name `e` rather than `eve` - a matter of preference, it'll work either way.)

Also your closing script tag is incorrect, you should have `</script>` not `<script>`.

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/oyoqeg/1/edit

(Note that displaying an alert on mousemove makes the page pretty much unusable, but that's another issue.)

Comment: Thank you it works for me, and for closing tag- apologies for same - it was typo mistake

Answer (score 2):

You have to define "eve" first. If eve is text you should use `my('eve')`, if eve is a variable you need to define it first with `var eve =... ;`

Otherwise if you might want to use `event` or `this`. `my(event)` or `my(this)`.